# How can I work out the class hierarchy given an object instance in Python?

Tags: python, inheritance, oop

Is there anyway to discover the base class of a class in Python?

For given the following class definitions:

```
class A:
   def speak(self):
      print "Hi"

class B(A):
   def getName(self):
      return "Bob"
```

If I received an instance of an object I can easily work out that it is a B by doing the following:

```
instance = B()
print B.__class__.__name__
```

Which prints the class name 'B' as expected.

Is there anyway to discover that the instance of an object inherits from a base class as well as the actual class?

Or is that just not how objects in Python work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
b = B()
b.__class__
b.__class__.__base__
b.__class__.__bases__
b.__class__.__base__.__subclasses__()
```

I strongly recommend checking out ipython and use the tab completion :-)

Comment: Interestingly, ipython doesn't see __bases__, but evaluating it is ok. I guess __base__ doesn't exist in 2.5, since that's no good for me.

Comment: I'd pay close attention to the version specific Python docs when really using interfaces which are that close to the Python core functionality. That should give you an idea of whether __base__ or __bases__ are to be preferred.

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html only talks about __bases__.

Comment: Oh, and I am running Python 2.6 (for the record).

Answer (score 8):

The inspect module is really powerful also:

```
>>> import inspect

>>> inst = B()
>>> inspect.getmro(inst.__class__)
(<class __main__.B at 0x012B42A0>, <class __main__.A at 0x012B4210>)
```

Answer (score 6):

Another way to get the class hierarchy is to access the **mro** attribute:

```
class A(object):
    pass
class B(A):
    pass
instance = B()
print(instance.__class__.__mro__)
# (<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <type 'object'>)
```

Note that in Python 2.x, you must use "new-style" objects to ensure they have the
**mro** attribute. You do this by declaring

```
class A(object):
```

instead of

```
class A():
```

See http://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/ and http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/ for more info new-style objects and mro (method resolution order).

In Python 3.x, all objects are new-style objects, so you can use **mro** and simply declare objects this way:

```
class A():
```

Answer (score 1):

If instead of discovery of the baseclass (i.e reflection) you know the desired class in advance you could use the following [built in functions](http://python.org/doc/2.5/lib/built-in-funcs.html)

eg:

```
# With classes from original Question defined
>>> instance = A()
>>> B_instance = B()
>>> isinstance(instance, A)
True
>>> isinstance(instance, B)
False
>>> isinstance(B_instance, A) # Note it returns true if instance is a subclass
True
>>> isinstance(B_instance, B)
True
>>> issubclass(B, A)
True
```

> **isinstance(     object, classinfo)**
> Return true if the object argument is an instance of the classinfo
> argument, or of a (direct or indirect)
> subclass thereof. Also return true if
> classinfo is a type object and object
> is an object of that type. If object
> is not a class instance or an object
> of the given type, the function always
> returns false. If classinfo is neither
> a class object nor a type object, it
> may be a tuple of class or type
> objects, or may recursively contain
> other such tuples (other sequence
> types are not accepted). If classinfo
> is not a class, type, or tuple of
> classes, types, and such tuples, a
> TypeError exception is raised. Changed
> in version 2.2: Support for a tuple of
> type information was added.
>
> **issubclass(     class, classinfo)**
> Return true if class is a subclass (direct or indirect) of classinfo. A
> class is considered a subclass of
> itself. classinfo may be a tuple of
> class objects, in which case every
> entry in classinfo will be checked. In
> any other case, a TypeError exception
> is raised. Changed in version 2.3:
> Support for a tuple of type
> information was added.